# Re-using the 'add campaign members' contact search for a custom object

Tags: visualforce, contact, leads, campaign, campaign-member

When managing a campaign, there's the 'add campaign members' functionality where one can query for contacts / leads and add them to the campaign.

I have a custom object where I also need to add contacts to. I would like to use the same functionality as is used on campaigns.

What would be the best way to build this type of behaviour? There's no out-of-the-box component to do that, right?

Answer (score 1):

Custom objects with Contacts in a standard report will have access to the Add to Campaign button.

If you must build this yourself, there is a good example of some add to campaign code, although this doesn't cover the search/filtering aspect. This is the repository for the Campaign Combiner app on the AppExchange:

https://github.com/Groundwire/Campaign-Combiner

Comment: What do you mean by 'with contacts'? A lookup field on contact that points to the custom object?

Let's say I implemented it that way, then I am looking for a component / visualforce page that I can put on the custom object page layout, where it will let the user add contacts to the custom object. That doesn't exist, right?